Jax random matrices running out of memory
I want to create an Nxk matrix in jax, where each row has k DISTINCT integer entries each between 0 and N-1 (so, in range(N)), and this was my attempt:
def generate_row(N, k, key):
    return jax.random.choice(key, N, (k,), replace=False)

generate_rows = jax.vmap(generate_row, in_axes=(None, None, 0))

def generate_mat(N, k, key=jax.random.PRNGKey(0)):
  keys = jax.random.split(key, N)
  return generate_rows(N, k, keys)

Now, when I use this for small arrays, it works wonderfully, however, for N = 50000, k=20 it blows out of memory, which confuses me greatly. What is taking up all of the space? And how do I do this right?

You can use permutations??

@user24714692 Sorry, I underspecified the question, see the edit.

What are you doing that you need an actual 50,000x20 matrix, though?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That is a question that can be asked essentially every StackOverflow poster, don't you think? The stock answer, I suppose, would be: well, I could tell you, but then...

No, I don't. I think everyone has different things they're working on, and very few need matrices this huge =) You might have a very good reason to need this, but saying what that reason is helps future visitors understand if your question is their question or whether they're better served with an answer that goes "don't so this, you can achieve the actual desired result much better by doing [X}".

jax.random.choice(key, N, (k,), replace=False) works by generating an array of length N, and then selecting k values from it.
In your vmap, you're vectorizing this function over N keys, which means you are generating an array of shape (N, N) and selecting (N, k) values from this array. When N = 50,000, the (N, N) array has 2,500,000,000 entries (about 10GB for 32-bit elements).
Doing better is a bit difficult: JAX generates non-repeating samples by permuting the sample space, and I don't know of a better algorithm for generating non-repeating samples.
For the case of N=50,000 and k=20, the best thing may  be to sample with replacement (which is much more efficient) and then check for rows with collisions (which will happen in about 1 of every 200 rows) and re-draw these until you have non-colliding entries.
Another option would be to use lax.map instead of lax.vmap: this is an iterative mapping rather than a vectorized mapping, so you can draw repeated samples without allocating the full (N, N) array.
If you don't need your random values to have any particular statistical properties, another option may be to draw values with repetition between 0 and N //k , and then add jnp.arange(0, N, N // k) to ensure that the values in each row are unique.

Thank you! I do want my samples to be uniform, so the last method, sadly, does not work. But for the others:

Is lax.map reasonably fast (presumably we would jit it).
For your first suggestion (sampling with replacement, then re-draw from the "bad" rows): Can this be done efficiently in jax?

And finally,

The method used by jax seems very strange. The usual algorithm to generate random permutations can be stopped after k steps, without the horrible memory penalty.

Thank you!

There are iterative approaches to sampling without replacement in a stepwise manner, but these have very poor performance on accelerators, which is why JAX uses truncated permutation.

By the way, I did try the map approach, it was horribly slow, though maybe I was doing something wrong.

As for your last comment, I understand, unfortunately it does limit the applicability, as we see.

as for your last comment, for k << N, your approach (sampling with replacement, then iterating if needed) is a good way to do it for JAX itself, especially since JAX sorts very fast.

An iterative sampling-with-replacement solution wouldn't be suitable for JAX library code, because the number of required iterations is unbounded, which makes it hard for the compiler to execute it efficiently on accelerators, and it also precludes normal reverse-mode autodiff.

I think I figured out a better way - see my other answer here.

Here is an efficient way to repeatedly generate k samples without replacement in the case of small k and large N. The memory requirements for generate_mat scale as ~O[Nk], but this comes at the cost of an ~O[Nk^2log(k)] runtime and ~O[k^4] jit-compile time, so this is not a great solution as k grows larger.
import jax

def generate_row(N, k, key):
  assert 0 <= k <= N
  vals = jax.random.randint(key, (k,), minval=0, maxval=N - jnp.arange(k))
  for i in range(len(vals)):
    for v in vals[:i].sort():
      vals = vals.at[i].add(vals[i] >= v)
  return vals

generate_rows = jax.vmap(generate_row, in_axes=(None, None, 0))

def generate_mat(N, k, key=jax.random.PRNGKey(0)):
  keys = jax.random.split(key, N)
  return generate_rows(N, k, keys)

generate_mat(50000, 20)

On a normal Colab CPU runtime this compiles in ~8 seconds, executes in ~2 seconds, and does not run into memory issues.

Interesting, I will try it, thanks!
